# in Mars Assembly .word with double quotes vs single quotes

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

When saving .word value to memory in .data section I encountered two situations:

*I know that .word are for storing an integer, but why the second line works and the first one doesn't?

```
.data
    firstWord: .word "A"
    secondWord: .word 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually assemblers and compilers allow to express an ASCII code number associated to an ASCII character by enclosing it between single quotes.

The first definition (`firstWord`) has a constant string so it yields an error when assembling your source because it's not an integer word.

The second definition (`secondWord`) has an ASCII code number, the one which corresponds to the `A` letter (`65`), so it's a valid integer word.